# Как поставить список чтобы он был справа?

Tags: html, ul

```css
ul.header-blog li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;

}
.header-blog {
 right: 0;
}
```

```html
   <ul class="header-blog">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Portfolio</li>
    <li>Testimonial </li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
   </ul>
```

Как поставить список чтобы он был справа

Comment: `position: absolute` добавить в `.header-blog`

Comment: В каком смысле справа? Что бы знаки списка были справа или что бы текст списка был справа?

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul.header-blog {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  right: 0;
}

ul.header-blog li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-blog">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Testimonial </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul.header-blog {
  float: right;
}

ul.header-blog li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="header-blog">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>Services</li>
  <li>Portfolio</li>
  <li>Testimonial </li>
  <li>Blog</li>
  <li>Contact Us</li>
</ul>
```